# PHP/Javascript not properly moving up and down the folders

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I have a simple contact form. In the directory there is main.html and 2 folders. folder1 contains the js code and folder2 contains the php file. The js file calls the php file to analyze some form data and the php file returns it to js file which ultimately outputs on main.html.

When the JS file is being called from the main.html, there is no data being sent back from the php file. This is what I use in the JS file

```
 $.post("../folder2/contact_form.php",
```

However, if I place main.html into folder 3 and call the JS file using this line it works.

```
 <script src="../test/contact_form.js"></script>
```

Basically, when main.html is inside a folder, the code works. If main.html is in the root folder, the php file isn't called when the JS file is accessed. Again, this code works but only when main.html is inside a folder.

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple jQuery Contact Form With Validation</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css" />
    <script src="../test/contact_form.js"></script>

</head>
    <body> 
        <div id="mainform">         
            <form id="form">

                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/><br/>

                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/><br/>

                <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"/><br/>

                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br/>

                <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send"/></td>

                <p id="returnmessage"></p><br/></td>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

contact_form.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();

    $("#returnmessage").empty(); //To empty previous error/success message.
//checking for blank fields 
if(name==''||email==''||subject=='')
{
   alert("Please Fill Required Fields"); 
}
else{
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("../test2/contact_form.php",{ name1: name, email1: email, message1:message, subject1: subject},
   function(data) {
                $("#returnmessage").append(data);//Append returned message to message paragraph
                    if(data=="Your message was sent successfully! Thank-You for contacting us!"){
                        $("#form")[0].reset();//To reset form fields on success
                    }
            });
         }

});
});
```

---

contact_form.php

```
<?php
//Fetching Values from URL
$name = $_POST['name1'];
$email = $_POST['email1'];
$message = $_POST['message1'];
$subject = $_POST['subject1'];
//sanitizing email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
//After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
$template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
. '<br/>Thank you...! For Contacting Us.<br/><br/>'
. 'Name:' . $name . '<br/>'
. 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'
. 'Subject:' . $subject . '<br/>'
. 'Message:' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
. 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
. '<br/>'
. 'We will contact you as soon as possible .</div>';
$sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" . $template . "</div>";
// message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);

// Send mail by PHP Mail Function
mail("asd@gmail.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
echo "Your message was sent successfully! Thank-You for contacting us!";

} else {
echo "<span>Please enter a valid email.</span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: the js file should post to a url relative to the html file. so try $.post("folder2/contact_form.php",

Comment: @madalinivascu - you mean up a level :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your folder structure is :

root/main.html

root/css/contact.css

root/test/contact_form.js

root/test2/contact_form.php

Then you urls don't need the `../`
exemple: `$.post("test2/contact_form.php",{},function(){})`

Comment: Thanks it worked! Still don't know how I am accessing php file without moving up the directory using ../

Comment: to use `../`you will need to move css,test and test2 to the parent folder of root